# ASP.NET get count of logged-In User

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to display number logged-In users count in my page. I implemented this using Application Variable, but the problem is its not decreasing the count when user close the browser.

First i opened the web application using IE the count became 1, then i opened the app using firefox the count became 2. When i close any one of the browser the count not getting decrease.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
      Application["UsersCount"] = 0;
}

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Application["UsersCount"] != null)
   {
      Application.Lock();
      Application["UsersCount"] = ((int)Application["UsersCount"]) + 1;
      Application.UnLock();
   }
}
void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Application.Lock();
      Application["UsersCount"] = ((int)Application["UsersCount"]) - 1;
      Application.UnLock();
}
```

Any other way to achieve this?

Thank you.!

Comment: `Session_End` only fires when the session times out on the server (the browser doesn't send information about closing), and then only if you're using `InProc` session state.

Comment: Yes, Is there any other way to count the users who accessing the application?

Comment: If you are using sessions what session state store are you using? `InProc`, `StateServer` or `SQLServer`?

Comment: @Peter - I am using InProc..

Answer (score 0):

This is not so simple to implement. To be *logged in* doesn`t actually necessary mean that user doing something. You should set some timeout (probably the same as auth cookie life-time) and check the last activity mark of each user. Special DB table is good for that, but if you want quick and dirty solution:

You can keep `IDictionary<Guid, DateTime>` which you will update on each request. Guid is for UserID, DateTime for the last activity. On each request (probably somewhere in MasterPage code behind) you update this dictionary with current DateTime. Then you can check count of IDs with DateTime less than timeout.

```
IDictionary<Guid, DateTime> userActivityLog = Application["UserActivityLog"] as IDictionary<Guid, DateTime>;
DateTime timeout = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1); // one hour timeout
int loggedCount = userActivityLog.Count(x => x.Value > timeout);
```

Comment: Thank you @Dzoukr, unfortunately if user opened the page n close it within couple of mins, it will still show their count till 1 hour right.

Comment: Yes... Actually there is no way how to find out, that they are not there (eating lunch with active session :)). You can possibly add some AJAX call when browser closing, but it is still inaccurate. Maybe, if you consider to be normal to "hit" your site once a minute, you can set timeout to few minutes. On the other hand, be inactive few minutes does not necessary mean that user closed browser - can be filling some long form or so. As said, not an easy task.